# find repeat patterns in webpages in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, search, html-parsing, pattern-matching

I am trying to find a way of finding repeat patterns in webpages so that i can extract the content into my database.

EDIT :   I don't know what the repeat pattern is before hand so i can't just search for a given pattern via a regex or something.

For example if you have 10 sites selling cars but the sites are all different, looking on each site the cars are listed in html in a repeated way down the page for this site.

The other sites will be listed in a different way but each with a repeated pattern.

Does anyone know how, or have any experience of this sort of thing?

i love ruby so was hoping to do it in ruby if any one has or knows of any libs / gems that may help me out ?

Comment: Can you give us a simple, dummy example to explain what you're trying to do? eg give us an example of a batch of the kind of repeated text/html you'd hope the code would catch?

Answer (score 2):

Rick, machine pattern matching is a complicated topic, and not something that you'll find a good library for out of the box on Ruby.

Kyle's answer was a start, once you get the page with Ruby, the typical techology for this would be [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) or "The XML Path Language".

Using Xpath you can write simple selectors that will extract every item matching a pattern, for instance, every link on an HTML document might be `//a`, every `h1` would be `//h1`, and every image directly inside a div, where the image has the class "car" would be something like: `//div/image[class="car"]`.

The result of the XPath is an enumerable list of each item, you can then query for sub-elements, get the `content()` of the elements, and build relationships to extract the data you need.

The go-to library for Ruby is called **Nokogiri**, and is [avaiable as a gem](http://nokogiri.org/) - the direct documentation is a little weak, but it's all covered there if you know what to look for.

Some libraries for Ruby combine the crawling, with an easy way to access the underlying HTML/XML as a Nokogiri document, one such example is [`Anemone`](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/) which is a "framework for building web spiders in Ruby" - and I can recomment it very highly.

Comment: thanks but the point is i dont know the pattern to match to, as all the sites will be different, therefore i need a more clever way find patterns on a webpage, something like this [Extracting Data Records from the Web
Using Tag Path Clustering](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:R4-JP26WuPkJ:www.uweb.ucsb.edu/~miao/pdf/p981.pdf+find+repeating+patterns+in+html+web+page&hl=en&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESgN-wtTra0Zbh162vIyoMgmy1qMYj9mJ9hDW0wfbuHnYepvUzBbcPCHI5sHEC0cBzcxPzu2T3wCyROaAlAA1nfADCv1Ah4sq6bLHIQR2P1Se9rnLxh-bMRbf0l9XPqLpVy8bATL&sig=AHIEtbQevRYUIeiNHVHv-SK4EJq3P9FY_g) any ideas ??

Comment: @rick: the paper you linked describes a strategy that sounds pretty good, have you tried implementing it or are you looking for an existing implementation?

Comment: @maerics:    no i only found that yesterday, i does sound rally good just want to check if this has been done or if anyone can give any tips etc before i try to implement it!! any ideas ???

Comment: @Rick, that was my point, there's no existing easy software, so you'd have to turn to academia to come up with some pattern matching resource… hopefully my advice helps you with the crawler part!

Answer (score -1):

In Ruby, if you want to get the text of a webpage all you have to do is use the `Net::HTTP` namespace. The `get` method returns a string representation of the webpage.

```
Net::HTTP.get 'http://www.target-site.com', '/target-page.html'
```

You're probably going to want to use some sort of XML Parser after that to make a model of the page and navigate over it. I've heard good things about `Hpricot`.

Comment: thanks but i know how to get the text from a webpage!!           I also don't want to write a model of the page as the point of this problem is that it could be any webpage!        I need to find a repeated pattern on each webpage so that i can split up a stocklist forexample into each item.     any ideas???

Comment: Ha. Okay, but if you figure out how to make code that reads pages and is able to figure out on its own what the format of the data is you're probably going to be up for a Nobel or something. Generally speaking you need to figure out the pattern manually and create a script that uses that format to scrape the info.

Comment: thats what my current spider does but want to improve it with some thing like this : Extracting Data Records from the Web
Using Tag Path Clustering   ??